# NodeJs,expressJs: webpack error : TypeError: mocha.useColors is not a function at configureMocha

Tags: webpack, mocha.js, istanbul, nyc

I am using :

```
{
"webpack": "^5.11.1",
"mocha-webpack": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
"nyc": "^15.1.0",
}
```

and i have usually 0% in coverage and this error when i am trying to cover my rest APIs made with express

NB:

- I am super beginner in testing
- I am using node v12.13.1 and express 4.17.1

[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfThW.png)

Answer (score 1):

For `"mocha": "^8.4.0"`

Although it works when using `mocha.color(true)`, typescript will complain: `error TS2339: Property 'color' does not exist on type 'Mocha'.`.

Instead this works fine: `mocha.options.color = true;`

Answer (score 0):

`useColors` was deprecated in Mocha 8. I think the `color` method should replace it.

Source: [PR removing `useColors` in `mochajs/mocha`](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/pull/4178)